# jQuery blockUI Auto Redirect

Tags: jquery, blockui

I'm using blockUI and its working really well.

The only thing I can't seem to get it too do is redirect to another URL after x amount of seconds. I can get it to redirect but it doesn't take into account the setTimeout...

Has anyone been able to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#demo2').click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ css: { 
                border: 'none', 
                padding: '15px',
                color: '#fff',
                backgroundColor: '#54bdd9', 
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                opacity: 1.5, 
                color: '#fff' 
            } }); 

            setTimeout($.unblockUI, 6000),$(window.location).attr('href', 'http://www.mydomain.co.uk');

        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

If anyone can shed any light it would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a while, but I just went looking for this. After experimenting, it seems BlockUI doesn't prevent a window navigation, so you don't even have to unblock it. Just delay and navigate.

```
$('#demo2').click(function () {
  $.blockUI({
    css: {
      border: 'none',
      padding: '15px',
      color: '#fff',
      backgroundColor: '#54bdd9',
      '-webkit-border-radius': '10px',
      '-moz-border-radius': '10px',
      opacity: 1.5,
      color: '#fff'
    }
  });

  setTimeout(function() { window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/"; }, 6000);
});
```

(There are various discussions about how to set the window location. I don't mean to discuss it here. This `window.location.href` is just the way I do it.)